# Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer client: Couldn't connect to server (Source: C# [Extension])

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3
VSCode: 1.83

Every time I open Visual Studio Code, an error pops up saying "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer client: Couldn't connect to server (Source: C# [Extension])".

Intellisense does not work for C# either, and I am unsure if it has to do with this error.

The following is the output:

```
Using dotnet configured on PATH
Dotnet path: /usr/bin/snap
Activating C# + C# Dev Kit + C# IntelliCode...
waiting for named pipe information from server...
[stderr] error: unknown command "/home/alex/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-2.6.24-linux-x64/.roslyn/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer.dll", see 'snap help'.
Language server process exited with 64
[Error - 10:30:55 AM] Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer client: couldn't create connection to server.
```

I don't know what is causing it. I have tried reinstalling VSCode and reinstalling my extensions. I have checked the filepath of the unknown command to see if the file was missing for some reason, but it is present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/391#issuecomment-1684483731) on github.

You can try to delete the folder found in (command 'open extensions folder'). Then reinstall the C# extension.

Comment: "the folder" which folder?

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -rf /Users/<YourName>/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools*
```

Then close all instances of VS Code and reopen and reinstall C# Dev Kit

Comment: Just did it, but unfortunately Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer is still consuming 1GB of memory while idle.